# Shorted capacitor

Tags: capacitor, relay, electrolytic-capacitor

The aim of the circuit below is to continuously switch power from one LED to another (**D1 & D2**).

[image: Circuit diagram made with Proto app. Yellow dots indicating the flow of electricity from positive to negative.]

The issue comes arises when I close the push switch (**SW2**) and an error message pops up saying that the capacitor **C1** has shorted. What happened and how could I fix it?

I haven't had a chance to practically test it yet.

Answer (score 2):

It's a side effect of using ideal lumped-constant models. Ideal voltage source cannot change its terminal voltage, switch SW2 has no resistance, capacitor C1 cannot instantaneously change its voltage, the inductor cannot instantaneously change its current. So the circuit as modeled here becomes a contradiction.

Add a small (0.1 ohm) resistor in series with the 9V battery, to model the real-world effects of the battery's internal source resistance. You can also add 0.1 ohm resistors in series with the capacitor and inductor, to model the resistance of the component leads and system wiring. These values are not exact, but including these "parasitic" resistances makes the model more "practical" (as opposed to ideal) and makes it possible for the machine to simulate the system.